# Trying to combine/merge two data frames in R, matching values in two columns and returning a third

Tags: r, merge

I'm trying to combine two data frames in R, using what I guess would be the equivalent of Excel's VLOOKUP function.

In one data frame, I have a list of events that occur in a hockey game (each game represented by a different season and "gcode") -- there are hundreds of rows per game.

I want to add a column that tells me whether the team won or lost. I have the results in a different data frame (a list of the results, with one row per game).

How can I use "merge()" or a similar function to do this? I would need the function to reference both the "season" and "gcode" in each data frame.

Here are two example data frames, and the result I want.

List of events:

```
     season gcode seconds score_dif
1  20072008 20001     145         2
2  20072008 20001    2055         1
3  20072008 20002     691         0
4  20082009 20053    3528        -1
5  20092010 20104    2787         1
6  20092010 20155    1752         1
7  20102011 20206    2929         0
8  20102011 20257     277         3
9  20102011 20308    2733        -2
10 20132014 20359    3890        -4
```

List of results:

```
     season gcode result
1  20072008 20001      1
2  20072008 20002      0
3  20072008 20003      1
4  20072008 20004      0
5  20072008 20005      0
6  20072008 20006      0
7  20072008 20007      0
8  20072008 20008      1
9  20072008 20009      0
10 20072008 20010      1
```

Combined:

```
     season gcode seconds score_dif result
1  20072008 20001     145         2      1
2  20072008 20001    2055         1      1
3  20072008 20002     691         0      0
4  20082009 20053    3528        -1      0
5  20092010 20104    2787         1      1
6  20092010 20155    1752         1      0
7  20102011 20206    2929         0      0
8  20102011 20257     277         3      0
9  20102011 20308    2733        -2      0
10 20132014 20359    3890        -4      1
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `dplyr` package

```
library(dplyr)

df <- events %>%
  left_join(results)
```

If it does not work correctly you can create in both `data.frames` a new column `join`:

```
events$join <- paste0(events$season,events$gcode)
results$join <- ...
```

and then

```
df <- events %>%
  left_join(results, by = "join")
```

Comment: Does anyone know how to do this in base R?